# to add a new column in data frame(df) that stores value of (total present)/(total present+total absent) for each individual

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

It is python Pandas data frame named as df .How do I add new column to it that stores `total present/(total present + total absent)` for each indivodual

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([None, 'Absent', 'Present'], (10, 10))
)
```

[image]

You can use `pd.value_counts` with `normalize=True`

```
df.join(df.apply(pd.value_counts, 1, normalize=True).Present)
```

[image]

Comment: ! wow you solved it in one line! i had to write atleast 10 steps for this! Please Check my answer, if any redundancy can be eliminated.

Comment: Hmmm, I check both solutions with same data and different output. It seems one of solution is bad, can you check it?

Comment: `df.assign(Present=df.stack().map(dict(Present=1, Absent=0)).unstack().mean(1))` on this data produces the same results.

Answer (score 1):

A dummy dataframe, for simplicity i have created `a,b,c,d` as column names

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['jon','sam','dean','bob'],
               'b': ['present','present','absent','present'],
               'c':['absent','present','present','absent'],
               'd':['absent','absent','present','present']})

df['b1'] = df['b'].map({'present': 1, 'absent': 0})
df['c1'] = df['c'].map({'present': 1, 'absent': 0})
df['d1'] = df['d'].map({'present': 1, 'absent': 0})

df['sum_1'] = (df[['b1','c1','d1']] == 1).sum(axis=1)
df['sum_0'] = (df[['b1','c1','d1']] == 0).sum(axis=1)

df['present'] =((df['sum_1']* 1.0)/(df['sum_1']+df['sum_0']))

df[['a','b','c','d','present']]
```

Or you can simply use this solution suggested by @piRSquared.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['jon','sam','dean','bob'],
           'b': ['present','present','absent','present'],
           'c':['absent','present','present','absent'],
           'd':['absent','absent','present','present']})
df.assign(present=df.stack().map(dict(present=1, absent=0)).unstack().mean(1))
```

[image]

Comment: Using you `df` and methodology  `df.assign(present=df.stack().map(dict(present=1, absent=0)).unstack().mean(1))`

Comment: Hmmm, I check both solutions with same data and different output. It seems one of solution is bad, can you check it?

Comment: @jezrael okay sir, but you can clearly see in my output, for the first row, there are 2 absent and 1 present, so it would be 1/(1+2) = 0.33
similarly for 2nd row `sam` there are 2 present and 1 absent. so result should be 2/(2+1) = 0.666 mathematically and i'm getting the same result.

Comment: Super, I think your solution is correct, maybe better is use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383784/to-add-a-new-column-in-data-framedf-that-stores-value-of-total-present-tota/43384477?noredirect=1#comment73830705_43384477) - dont worry, add it to answer.

Comment: @jezrael yes, sir :)